# How to Init get-only properties in C#

Tags: c#

I've made a class called Device which has the following properties:

```
public int Id { get; }
public string DeviceName { get; set; }
public string MACAddress { get; set; }
public string UUID { get; set; }
public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
public string Location { get; set; }
public string PinCode { get; }
```

I use these properties to get information from my database.

I then want to update the device in my database using the following:

```
private void _updateDeviceInDataBase()
{
    DataAccess database = new DataAccess();
    Device device = new Device()
    {
        DeviceName = textBox_PcNumber.Text,
        SerialNumber = DeviceProperties.GetSerialNumber(),
        UUID = DeviceProperties.GetUUID(),
        MACAddress = DeviceProperties.GetMACAddress(),
        Location = comboBox_Location.Text,
    };

    database.UpdateDevice(device);
}
```

My problem is, that my `Id` and my `PinCode` is null, because I obviously don't set them in my `device` variable.

My question then is - how do I make use of the properties `Id` and `PinCode` in my `device`, without having to change them to `set`?

Comment: Change them to `set` or `init`. Or don't use the same class for both querying and modifying data

Comment: How do you know which device to update in the database without an id anyway?

Comment: I wonder how you would update a new instance? Is the above just some dummy-code and you get the object from your database actually?

Comment: I'm relatively new to using properties, so I am not 100 percent sure, if the way I'm doing this is correct. However, my thought process was, that I don't want to be able to change the `PinCode` nor `Id`, as these are unique to the device. When I get the device, it already has the `Id` and `PinCode` in the database

Comment: You said you want to update the existing value.  So read the current values from database.  Then modify the old values with the new values.  If you do not have a new id then use the old id.

Comment: Then what exactly is your problem? If you got the device from the database, just set the properties you want to change and leave everything else unaffected. However your current code implies you don't retrieve the object from the db, but just create a completely new one.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain That's exactly what I want, but I don't get the `Id` nor `PinCode`. As I mentioned, I might be doing it wrong, so would you mind making an example?

Comment: As @PanagiotisKanavos suggests, use `init` or add a ctor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can init get-only properties in the constructor..

```
public class Device
{
    public int Id { get; }
    public string DeviceName { get; set; }
    public string MACAddress { get; set; }
    public string UUID { get; set; }
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string PinCode { get; }

    public Device(int id, string pinCode)
    {
        Id = id;
        PinCode = pinCode;
    }
    // other code ...
    // public Device(){} // uncomment this if you want to call new Device();
}
```

If initiating Id, PinCode properties is not required, you can uncomment `// public Device(){}` line.

Thanks to @Franck comment, you can set Id, PinCode properties via setter injection

```
public class Device
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string DeviceName { get; set; }
    public string MACAddress { get; set; }
    public string UUID { get; set; }
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string PinCode { get; private set;}
    
    public void SetId(int id) => Id = id;
    public void SetPinCode(string pinCode) => PinCode = pinCode;

    // other code ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Definitely a better way than what I've done it

Comment: @wads You could also make your intention clearer by adding the setter as private for those 2 variables for example `public string PinCode { get; private set; }` like that only your clase can set value into those properties internally and the intent is clear as day that it is not accessible outside.